# How to open a URL with Terminal through applescript by using mpg123?

Tags: terminal, applescript, homebrew

I need to use mac terminal to open an audio stream from a URL through an applescript. I know that mac terminal is already equipped with afplay, but that only plays a file which is available on your computer. An alternative is mpg123 which can be installed in mac by means of brew. My question is how I can use this command in an apple script.

Answer (score 1):

Command line programs can be run using the `do shell script "..."` command in AppleScript.  You can generally write a command as you would in *Terminal*, keeping in mind that double quotes need to be escaped with a preceding backslash `\`.  The `do shell script` command returns the last output to `stdout`.

So, for example:

```
do shell script "myvar=hello world; echo \"$myvar\""
```

will return `hello world` as a string.

These commands are run without a terminal, so can't interact with the user, e.g. to receive user input.  If you need a terminal, you can `tell application "Terminal" to tell the front window to tell the front tab to do script "..."`.

But, `do shell script "..."` is perfect for most situations where bash commands need to be employed.

If it's useful to know, *iTunes* can also play audio streams from the internet.  You can do this from the command line like this:

```
open -a itunes "http://ssl.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/20160317/pronunciation--_us_1.mp3"
```

From within AppleScript, this might look like:

```
do shell script "open -a itunes \"http://ssl.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/20160317/pronunciation--_us_1.mp3\""
```

or, using *iTunes* scriptability:

```
tell application "iTunes" to open location "http://ssl.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/20160317/pronunciation--_us_1.mp3"
```

Comment: But I prefer to play the sound through terminal. I specifically need to know the syntax for using mpg123 command so that terminal can play the sound.

Comment: Type this into _Terminal_: `man mpg123` and it'll bring up everything you need to know on how to use the command.